# How to create a record of a object after installation of managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package

I am developing a managed package. I want create some record after installation of this package. Is possible to run apex script after installation of the package?

Comment: Do you want to do it as part of the package installation?

Comment: 'yes' @BarCotter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Post Install Handler Interface](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm), this should allow you to create record after package is installed. you just need to create this Interface Class and then select that Class in "Post Install Handler" lookup in your Package Dev org.

Comment: Thanks @VarunC. The method `onInstall` of the interface  `InstallHandler` does it fire after update of a package?

Comment: Yes it fires every time package is installed, whether fresh install or an upgrade.